# Subtracting 1 to cell.textLabel.text causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

You can add and subtract `1` from my `cell.textLabel.text`. I am adding 1 with this method:

```
  - (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{

     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] +1];
     number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:num, nil];
     [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

And i cant get the textLabel to subtract! here is my method:

```
    - (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender
{
     if ( [[cell.textLabel text] intValue] == 0){  

     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[num intValue] +0];
     [number addObject:num];

     }
     else{

     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[num intValue] -1];
     [number addObject:num];

     }
}
```

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, i am trying to set the label's text with this line:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The + button works, but the - button doesnt. How could i fix this? Thanks in advance!

**CELLFORROW**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         addBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         addBtn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [addBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,25,55)];
         [addBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [addBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [addBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:addBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(260,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];
         //cell.textLabel.text = @"1";
     } 
    //cellText.hidden=!self.editing;

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where is your CRASH log ? Post it. When App crashes first thing one would look for is CRASH Log.

Comment: can we see your cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Also, are you using ARC with this project?

Comment: @Adam@ what is ARC? and yeah ill post both the cell for row and the crash log!

Comment: @0x8badf00d the crash log doesnt show anything, but i am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS warning/error!

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Google Search to figure out how to find what causes that

Comment: ARC is automatic reference counting, an alternative to manual memory management. If you aren't using ARC, then you have some serious memory management issues. The way you are using your `number` variable is also very questionable based on the code I see here.

Comment: BTW, Which iOS version you are working on , is it iOS5?

Comment: @AjaySharma yeah its IOS 5! why? does it affect the code that you provided? Thanks

Comment: @AdamW oh okay! that makes sense!! and what is wrong with how im using `number`? THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will crash because the cell is not the same cell on which your + and - buttons are there.
You have to get the "UITableViewCell" in which you clicked the "+" or "-" button. And then manipulate the text as you required.